# Regexp под определенный вид линков C#

Tags: c#

Не получается составить regexp для подобных ссылок:
`http://domen.com/rss.php?hash=h7n9hg5hg
http://domen.com/cont.php?d=123`

надо чтобы парсились строго линки с `.php?` и с указанным доменом обязательно а не все подряд и линки вида: `http://domen.com/cont.php?d=123&amp=234` так же не должны парсятся точнее часть начиная с `&`...

Помогите пожалуйста составить правильный патерн, больше 4 часов сижу не чего не выходит, точнее с условиями выше не выходит...

Comment: А где ваш код? Добавьте его в вопрос.

Comment: зачем вам код? мне именно патерн нужен правильный с этим беда...

Comment: В таком случае, где ваш патерн над которым вы 4 часа уже мудрите?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не все задачи хорошо решаются регулярками. Откройте для себя большой мир!

```
var s = "http://domen.com/lalala/rss.php?hash=h7n9hg5hg";
var uri = new Uri(s);

var queryDict = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
var isGoodDomain = uri.Host == "domain.com";
var isphp = uri.LocalPath.EndsWith(".php");
```

Если вы случайно пытаетесь выдрать адреса из HTML при помощи регулярок, используйте парсер.

Comment: да спасибо я об этом в курсе но это получается дополнительная обработка,  надо бы  как то именно регуляркой выдергивать, да пытаюсь выдрать именно с html все верно...

Comment: @GeneratorSveta: Ну, если хотите «попроще», дело ваше. Тривиальные две строчки на подключение парсера — сложная дополнительная обработка?

Comment: вы похоже оказались правы без доп обработки не вариант обойтись, спасибо большое...

Answer (score 0):

```
https?://domen\.com/[^?]+\.php\?[^=&]+=[^&]+
```